# A layout issue (NSLayoutConstraint) in an iOS app

Tags: swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In an iOS app I have an autolayout issue.

The 2 following screenshots show the problem.

[image]

[image]

The switch (UISwitch object) on the right is displaced horizontally, when it should be fixed. Can anyone see what is happening?

It is true that the string on the left is changing length, but I think (according to the way I have set the constraints up) the font should be resized or the string split in 2 lines; but not the switch displaced.

Here is the relevant swift code:

```
import UIKit

class My_ViewController: UIViewController {
    let xPanel = UILabel(), yPanel = UILabel(),
    khToggle = UISwitch(), khLabel = UILabel()
    ....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        layOutUI()
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        .....
        toggleKeepHide(khToggle)
    }


    func layOutUI() {
        for component in [xPanel,yPanel,khLabel,khToggle] {
            component.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(component)
        }

        ...........

        khLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        khLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        khToggle.addTarget(self,
                                 action: #selector(toggleKeepHide(_:)),
                                 for: .valueChanged)

        view.addConstraints([
            .........
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: khToggle, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0,    constant: -30.0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: khToggle, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: yPanel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: 50.0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: khLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: khToggle, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0,     constant: -23.0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: khLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: khToggle, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0,  constant: 0.0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: khLabel, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0,     constant: 30.0)])
    }


    @objc func toggleKeepHide(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {khLabel.text = "Hide this object from the wyxoug list."}
        else {khLabel.text = "Keep this object in the wyxoug list."}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal constraints for the label and the toggle are competing against each other.

(If you step in to Xcode's visual debugger, you'll find that there is a warning: the `UISwitch` instance has an ambiguous width and horizontal position.)

[image]

**Solution**

You have provided absolute values to AutoLayout, and it cannot resolve the requirements. To fix this, introduce some flexibility in to the requirements by setting the compression resistance of the label to a lower value:

```
khLabel.setCompressionResistance(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

[image]

Comment: Using setContentCompressionResistancePriority does the job. But I don't quite understand why there is ambiguity about the width (I don't fix any width), beside the right of the UISwitch is fixed, since it must be a fixed object I assume its horizontal position is perfectly determinated.

Comment: You are telling AutoLayout to pin the layouts to exact values, relative to objects and the superview. But it cannot resolve those exact values against the intrinsic widths of the properties. By providing a lower compression resistance for one of the items, you are telling AutoLayout that one of the item's widths can be be reduced, allowing it to resolve the layout.

Comment: OK, I see. This was implicit in my mind that the AutoLayout was free to compress or fold the label. This was my mistake. Though it seems to sometime work that way.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not just you. It's a difficult set of APIs, particularly with multi-line labels. Hopefully, one day a few years from now, SwiftUI will make some of these issues a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided sufficient information to reproduce the problem. Here's a reduction of your code, in my view controller's `viewDidLoad` (I eliminated everything but the label and the switch, fixed your `left` and `right` (you should never use those), and changed the alignment between the two views to `top` instead of `center`):

```
    khToggle = UISwitch()
    khToggle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(khToggle)

    khLabel = UILabel()
    khLabel.text = String(repeating: "word ", count: 40)
    khLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(khLabel)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    khLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    view.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: khToggle!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0,    constant: -30.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: khToggle!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0,
                           constant: 50.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: khLabel!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: khToggle, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0,     constant: -23.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: khLabel!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: khToggle, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0,  constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: khLabel!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0,     constant: 30.0)])
```

The result displays fine; there are no constraint conflicts or ambiguities, and it looks as one would expect:

[image]

Comment: Interesting answer. What is wrong about using .left and .right; you may be right about not using them but it would be nice to have some explanations (even short or just a link). I never had any issue with them up to now. Beside you use .leading and .trailing which I may have never used. Here also I may be wrong, though I have successfully used NSLayoutConstraint many times.

Comment: Using leading and trailing is the preferred way to do it. It allows UIKit to flip the presentation for right-to-left languages such as Hebrew and Arabic.

Comment: matt, the problem is more easily reproduced by using a smaller device width, and increasing the number of words in the label text. As Michel points out, the UISwitch will be repositioned. Using a lower compression resistance priority on the label will fix the issue. Cheers.

Comment: @Womble Well I don't think that explains it, since I _did_ increase the words in the label text. A lot. As you can see. And the switch didn't move.

Comment: @matt, that's weird. I was able to reproduce it using his constraints, Using Simulator iPhone XR, iOS 12. What happens if you use 'left' and 'right' instead of 'leading', 'trailing'?